# c++ winapi listview NM_CUSTOMDRAW: not getting CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I'm trying to change the row text-color of a list-view I made from a resource. For that, I handle `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` inside my dialog process. It's a modal dialog box, if that matters. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff919573(v=vs.85).aspx),
 `dwDrawStage` should equal `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` after returning `CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW`. But this is not the case. I'm receiving `CDDS_PREPAINT` for every item.

What did I do wrong?

This is how I respond to the message:

```
        case WM_NOTIFY:

        if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom == GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_List2) && ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) 
        {
            int result = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
            LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
            switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
            {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                    result = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                    break;
                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: //never gets executed
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                    result = CDRF_NEWFONT;
                    break;
            }

            //SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, DWLP_MSGRESULT, result);
            //return TRUE;
            return result;
        }
        break;
```

these are the properties of the ListView:

```
IDC_List2,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_NOLABELWRAP | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | LVS_NOSORTHEADER | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,205,18,363,197,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
```

Comment: It is more convoluted when you use the details view (LVS_REPORT), you'll have to custom-draw the sub-items.  That requires returning CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW | CDRF_NEWFONT from the CDDS_PREPAINT stage.  [Mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919573(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with coloring the entire row for now, but I can't even get that to work in my program. I did a bit of testing and made a new test project with a virtual listview where I handled the notification in the window process (so no dialog), and it worked. Maybe it doesn't work because of the modal dialog box?

Comment: [Returning values from a dialog procedure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923).

Comment: Your comment made me recheck my code and I found that I was setting the wrong window for `SetWindowLongPtr()`, thanks! Now I'm finally getting `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT`.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem:
`WM_NOTIFY` is handled inside a dialog so of course I have to [return the values accordingly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923). The issue was, that I used the wrong variable for the window (`hEdit` in this case).

This is the corrected version if anyone cares:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:

        if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom == GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_List2) && ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) 
        {
            int result = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
            LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
            switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
            {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                    result = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                    break;
                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                    result = CDRF_NEWFONT;
                    break;
            }
            SetWindowLongPtr(hDialog, DWLP_MSGRESULT, result);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Good remark, the SetWindowLongPtr must point to the DIALOG instead of the control.